# How to filter table in mat-expansion-panel? by column

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material, angular8

I am using mat-expansion-panel with mat-accordion to create a table with fold/unfold events:

[image: Table with mat-accordion]

Here is my associated code:

```
<mat-accordion [multi]="true" displayMode="flat" class="mat-table font-size">
  <section class="mat-header-row">
    <div class="mat-header-cell client">**<input type="text" placeholder="Client">**</div>
    <div class="mat-header-cell siren">**<input type="text" placeholder="N° SIREN">**
    </div>
    <div class="mat-header-cell code">Code</div>
    <div class="mat-header-cell id">ID</div>
    <div class="mat-header-cell usage">Usages</div>
  </section>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let client of offerClients; let index = index;">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header [ngClass]="{'ligne-pair': index%2 == 0,'ligne-impair': index%2 != 0}">
      <img src="assets/Arrow_down.png">
      <div class="client">{{client.shortName}}</div>
      <div class="siren">{{client.siren}}</div>
      <div class="code">{{client.code}}</div>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let usage of client.usage">
          <td class="client"></td>
          <td class="siren"></td>
          <td class="code"></td>
          <td class="id">{{usage.id}}</td>
          <td class="usage">{{usage.usageName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

I know that filter option is not integrated natively in **mat-expansion-panel** component 
But I need to filter on each column according to the filter input : `<input type="text" placeholder="Client">`

Please do you know any simple way to implement it ?

Comment: You would need to filter the usage array based on the input value

Comment: Hello @DerekKite I need to filter client array in mat-expansion-panel

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter data that are pushed to be rendered in table one of ways of doing it is this:

```html
        <tr *ngFor="let usage of filter(client.usage)">
          <td class="client"></td>
          <td class="siren"></td>
          <td class="code"></td>
          <td class="id">{{usage.id}}</td>
          <td class="usage">{{usage.usageName}}</td>
        </tr>
```

where `filter` function is something like this:

```js
filter(list) {
  return list.filter(({ col1, col2, ... }) => !this.filter.col1 || col1 === this.filter.col1 && !this.filter.col2 || col2 === this.filter.col2);
}
```